# nhibernate - duplicating new child record insertion while updating parent

Tags: nhibernate, parent-child

Category and Subcategory have 1 to Many relationship. In update mode for category, I want to delete all existing subcategories and re-insert the new one (as scenario demands it). Deletion is happening fine, however the new child records are getting duplicated (If I've 2 new records for child, operation is inserting 2 + 2 records)

```
ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession().GetSession(EntityMode.Poco);
        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            List<Vtsubcategory> oovtsc = new List<Vtsubcategory>();
            oovtsc = oVtcategory.FkTocategory.Where(e => e.IdvtSubCategory != 0).ToList();
            foreach (Vtsubcategory ooVtsubcategory in oovtsc)
            {
                oVtcategory.FkTocategory.Remove(ooVtsubcategory);
                session.Delete(ooVtsubcategory);
            }
            session.SaveOrUpdateCopy(oVtcategory);
            session.Flush();
            if (tx.IsActive)
            {
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }
```

I guess it is inserting the child records in Save mode (for Child as they are new) and Inserting 2 more in Update (Parent) mode. Not sure if this is true and how to address it.

mapping is

```
<class name="Vtcategory" table="`vtcategory`" lazy="false">
<id name="IdvtCategory" column="`idvtCategory`" type="int">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>
<property type="string" length="100" name="Catname" column="`catname`" />
<property type="string" length="45" name="Catshortname" column="`catshortname`" />
<property type="DateTime" name="Crdt" column="`crdt`" />
<property type="string" length="45" name="Crby" column="`crby`" />
<bag name="FkTocategory" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="all">
  <key column="`catid`" />
  <one-to-many class="AMSDAL.Vtsubcategory,AMSDAL" />
</bag>
```

```
  <class name="Vtsubcategory" table="`vtsubcategory`" lazy="false">
<id name="IdvtSubCategory" column="`idvtSubCategory`" type="int">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>
<property type="string" length="100" name="Subcatname" column="`subcatname`" />
<property type="string" length="45" name="Subcatshortname" column="`subcatshortname`" />
<property type="DateTime" name="Crdt" column="`crdt`" />
<property type="string" length="45" name="Crby" column="`crby`" />
<many-to-one name="Catid" cascade="none" column="`catid`" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark one side of the relationship as the inverse. This is typically the one side on a one-to-many:

```
<bag name="FkTocategory" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all">
    <key column="`catid`" />
    <one-to-many class="AMSDAL.Vtsubcategory,AMSDAL" />
</bag>
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie, however this suggestion didn't help me and also leaves fk reference id in child as NULL.

Comment: changed this  ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession().GetSession(EntityMode.Poco) to ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession(), looks like it is fine now. Will test on more such scenarios that I have and will be back if I hit the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the cascade on the bag to be `all-delete-orphan` rather than `all`. Then in your code you can just assign the new list with the new subcategories to the FkToCategory property. This will ensure that all orphaned subcategories will be deleted automatically by NHibernate.